# Can I have a central profile in Atom editor like in chrome to install plugins automatically?

Tags: atom-editor

I moved from sublime to Atom and like the big choice of plugins. However, I have more computers, where the atom is installed and I want to have the possibility if I have installed atom to synchronize my plugins and settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are [several packages](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=sync) that sync your installed packages across computers.

If you're using Dropbox, Google Drive or the likes, you could always sync packages using symbolic links.